# How to replace custom attributes with jquerys data() method, inside XSLT?

Tags: jquery, xslt

I have the following input element:

```
<input type="radio">
        <xsl:attribute name="name">
          <xsl:value-of select="../../os:Row_ID "/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="row_id">
          <xsl:value-of select="../../os:Row_ID "/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="column_id">
          <xsl:value-of select="os:Column_ID "/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="value">
          <xsl:value-of select="../../os:Row_ID "/>
          <xsl:value-of select="os:Column_ID "/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </input>
```

Instead of using custom attributes, which dont get validated in the W3C validator, i want to use jQuerys data() method on:

```
    <xsl:attribute name="row_id">
      <xsl:value-of select="../../os:Row_ID "/>
    </xsl:attribute>
    <xsl:attribute name="column_id">
      <xsl:value-of select="os:Column_ID "/>
```

So i can add "row_id" as the key, and the value of `<xsl:value-of select="../../os:Row_ID "/>` as the value.

How would i accomplish this, inside XSLT?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<input 
  type="radio" 
  name="{../../os:Row_ID}"
  value="{../../os:Row_ID}{os:Column_ID}"
  data-row_id="{../../os:Row_ID}"
  data-column_id="{os:Column_ID}"
/>
```

Note that using `<xsl:attribute>` is superfluous unless you have variable attribute names. You can use attribute value templates (the `{expressions in braces}`) to assign values.

Comment: he wants to use jquery to bypass validation

Comment: @neu-rah `data-` attributes are valid as of HTML5 and they work without any problems with HTML4. Personally, I don't care if the W3C validator complains about them.